# Altering stored procedure on visual studio and generate schema compare

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

We are using SQL Server 2014 with Visual Studio 2015, we have a database project and a database.

Some programmers like to update procedures on visual studio and some others from management studio.

We have an issue, if you create the db project from database, all files created, for example stored procedures are generated with CREATE in tfs, same way the sp is saved on the database. When I do schema compare, all match. If someone use visual studio for altering one sp, he needs to change the file putting ALTER, this will allow developer to update the sp in the db from visual studio.

Now if I do schema compare again from db to tfs, I will have a new object to add in tfs because in the database is with CREATE and in tfs is with ALTER.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: couldn't the developers workflow be, rather than changing `create` to `alter` and attempting to run the change on the db, use the schema compare between their local SSDT project and the local dev database to generate the delta scripts?

Comment: I was wondering if there is an specific parameter to handle this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by specific parameter.  It requires a standard workflow for your development team, is that what you mean?

Comment: I about how schema compares works and how developers should work on TFS for updating an stored procedure. Right now if they alter one sp and then we do schema compare, it will show the difference just because in the db we have CREATE and on TFS we have ALTER

Comment: Seems more like a process issue. If they check out the stored proc directly to run against SQL, have them change their "ALTER" to a "CREATE" before they check it back in.  Besides, an ALTER PROC shouldn't work as part of the SSDT SQL Project.

Answer (score 1):

```
If someone use visual studio for altering one sp
```

This is the part that doesn't really fit with the "standard" SSDT workflow. SSDT generally assumes you are going to build a project (with or without TFS) and then update the whole database at once using "publish".

If you *need* to deploy single objects from Visual Studio, there are a couple of options such as "Quick Deploy" from https://agilesql.club/Projects/SSDT-Dev-Pack. This extension will let you deploy a single object (of some types) without changing the `CREATE` to an `ALTER` but bear in mind that using tools like this for routine deployment gives up many of the benefits (validation etc) of using SSDT in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

"If someone use visual studio for altering one sp, he needs to change the file putting ALTER, this will allow developer to update the sp in the db from visual studio."

This is where you're going wrong. You mustn't change the files in the SSDT database project from CREATE to ALTER. If you want to alter an object in a connected manner (ie, on the database) you have a couple of options:

1) Open a query window (either in SSMS or from the Server Object Explorer) and execute an ALTER (note that this ALTER just gets executed and not saved in the project). You then run Schema Compare between the database and the project and apply changes to the project. Note that this isn't the supported/preferred workflow of SSDT. Instead it is designed to be used offline by changing the CREATE files, but this model won't work in SSMS.

2) You can consider [ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/), which is developed at Redgate where I work. This is a database project in Visual Studio but it supports the connected workflow, which means that developers can make changes to a dev DB in either VS or SSMS and these changes can be imported back to the database project in a mouse click. This option has the advantage of being able to use the same development methodology in VS and SSMS alike.